# Add pointer to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com in our Help's 'on-topic' section?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Could we add a link to:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ in https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

regarding recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Software Recommendations is still alive one year after question was posted I think that a link to it will be helpful to both sites.

This will be helpful to that site as it could get more traffic and increase it relevance and eventually graduate and will be helpful to Web Applications to eventually reduce off-topics questions.

Comment: As a matter of policy, migration paths are not set to sites that are still in beta. However, they're trying to get sites out of beta faster, so maybe it can be re-visited soon.

Comment: [Congratulations! Software Recommendations is graduating!](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/14228) (Sep 2015)

Answer (score 3):

Probably not a good idea.

The software recommendations site is still in beta, and while it looks like it's doing OK, there's no guarantee it'll survive. So while it's probably OK to point people there in comments, it's a little early to make a (semi-)permanent link from our site.

Comment: The more we point to software recommendations, the less likely they'll disappear, right? Wouldn't this be a good idea to support them and helping webapps users to get answers for their questions at the same time?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I see your point, but I'm wary of linking to beta sites in the "official" documentation. As I said, linking in comments is fine.

Comment: Why would such a link be (semi-)permanent? Couldn't you remove it in case  softwarerecs.stackexchange.com get closed? (which is pretty unlikely as it is already much more active than webapps... 1000 questions in its two first months, vs. 15K questions on webapps since it got launched 4 years ago)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - It's in the help which is moderator editable, but requires us to keep up to date with the status of the Software Recommendations site to ensure it's always correct. If the site closes we would be pointing people at a non-existent site for however long it takes us to notice.

Comment: I guess a dead link in the help's on-topic section would be quickly pointed out on meta to be corrected. IMHO it's much better for users to know on which website to ask rather and then having a deadlink for a few days/weeks than users never knowing where to post.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt and ChrisF: If there's still room, to add another link option, then I second the thoughts of Franck.

Comment: Also, http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic does point to a beta SE (Quantitative Finance - Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 2):

IMO an excellent idea. (And arguments about beta sites irrelevant since Software Recommendations has graduated).