# Improve webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: Link to Stackexchange Softwarerecommendations

Tags: support, help-center

I noticed, that this has already been asked:

[Add pointer to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com in our Help's 'on-topic' section?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/add-pointer-to-softwarerecs-stackexchange-com-in-our-helps-on-topic-section)

And the accepted answer says: Yes we should add a link to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

However, that link still does't exist. Is there a reason against it?

(As that question was answered with 'it should be changed' but it still isn't changed, I've tagged this question as [bug])

---

In the

> #### Please note that the following subjects are considered *off*-topic here:

section, I'd recommend to replace the line

> - Web application recommendation requests

with a line like

> - Web application recommendation requests, ask [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead and use the [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps)-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Help center has now been updated with a pointer

Comment: Thanks! Maybe also mention the [web-apps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps)-tag? Also, should I delete this question, now, that the problem is solved and this question does no longer serve a purpose?

Comment: @TS no need to delete, let this be around for reference